# keras merge error, and keywork not understood

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, softmax

I am trying to build embedding for each example (i.e positive, negative, anchor ) . then calculate the triplet loss between their embedding, after applies softmax or euclidean distance or any other custom loss on the triplet loss value to minimize it training. However i encounter keras merge error. Bellow is summary of what i wanna do

```
positive_embedding = embedding_network(positive_example)
negative_embedding = embedding_network(negative_example)
anchor_embedding = embedding_network(anchor_example)

loss = merge([anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding],
                 mode=triplet_loss, output_shape=(10,))
 model = Model(inputs=[anchor_example, positive_example, negative_example],
                  outputs=loss)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
```

Comment: are you looking for Concatenate()([x,y,z]) ?

Comment: then how do i calculate the triplet loss between their embedding ?

Comment: you are using loss='categorical_crossentropy' ?!?

Comment: https://github.com/noelcodella/tripletloss-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/tripletloss.py